# Hibernate validator issue in spring boot on PCF

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

Deployment to Pivotal cloud foundry of my spring boot app fails with the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
```

Using its java **buildpack 4.17.2**

Problem only in cloud foundry deployment, locally works fine.
Cleaned up dependencies, using spring boot 1.5.19 and its started validator.

How to get rid of this missing dependency? spring-boot-starter-validation includes hibernate validator.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.37:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.18.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- wsl-java-validate:wslvalidate4:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- wsl-java-validate:asn1:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- wsl-java-validate:jsafe:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- wsl-java-validate:certj:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.15:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java7:jar:2.4.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.19.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.22.RELEASE:test
```

**EDIT:**

**FIXED.** Turns out it has been a problem caused by below jboss libraries I have picked up from another module of my webapp.
After excluding below libraries from target jar file, all works as expected.
Still strange my local deployments did not detect similar hibernate validator issues, need to understand more diffs between PCF java build packs and local java runtime.

```
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.rpc:jaxrpc-impl:jar:1.1.3_01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.rpc:jaxrpc-spi:jar:1.1.3_01:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jboss:jbossws-core:jar:1.0.4.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- jboss:jboss-common-client:jar:4.0.4.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- jboss.jbossws:jboss-jaxws-ext:jar:3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jbossxb:jar:2.0.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-spi:jar:2.0.5.GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss:jboss-common-core:jar:2.2.9.GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss:jboss-reflect:jar:2.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |     +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.wutka:dtdparser:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |     \- sun-jaxb:jaxb-api:jar:2.1.9:compile
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that Cloud Foundry or the Java buildpack are causing this issue. Neither are going to install or remove Hibernate dependencies from your application. It's more likely that the issue surfaces on CF because it's a clean environment to run your app. You might try running your app in a Docker container or on someone else's PC, you'll probably see the same issues.

Comment: As far as your issue: 1.) review and double check your pom.xml 2.) review the WAR/JAR that's generated and make sure it has the expected hibernate dependency 3.) review the path you're using with `cf push`, maybe you're pointing to the wrong WAR/JAR 4.) clean, build & try pushing again

Comment: Also, you can try to exclude this dependency like this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html